# Modify Chrome command line for default browser in Windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In order to debug a crashing extension, I need to modify the command line which is used to launch Chrome from another application as a default browser in Windows. I want to add the logging argument `--enable-logging --v=1`

Answer (score 2):

Command line can be modified in the registry:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command